# Applying sprite images using AlphaImageLoader

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I am trying to use AlphaImageLoader for a PNG image but my image is a sprite image. I am not getting the output of my sprite image when I use AlphaImageLoader in CSS. How can I use AlphaImageLoader for sprites? Can I use it for sprites?

Comment: I managed to get the output of sprite image using AlphaImageLoader but I am not able to set the particular position for it

Answer (score 1):

The [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) script allows for `background-position`, using VML instead of `AlphaImageLoader`.

> This is a Javascript library that
>   sandwiches PNG image support into IE6
>   without much fuss.
>
> You can use PNGs as the SRC of an
>   `<IMG/>` element or as a
>   `background-image` property in CSS.
>
> If you attempt the latter, you will
>   find that, unlike with vanilla usage
>   of `AlphaImageLoader`,
>   `background-position` and
>   `background-repeat` work as intended.
>
> As a bonus, "fixed" elements will
>   respond to a commonly used set of
>   Javascript style assignments, as well
>   as the `a:hover` pseudo-class.

Comment: but I want to applyy this for sprite image how can I do that

Comment: but I want to applyy this for sprite image how can I do that

Comment: @Vipul Look at the Usage section of the webpage: http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/#usage You need to include the Javascript file, then call the `DD_belatedPNG.fix()` function with a CSS selector that selects the elements you need to fix PNG transparency for.